# how to convert lambda expression to object directly?

Tags: c#, object, lambda

I have to do through Action like this:

```
Action action = () => { ..// };
object o = action;
```

any way to do this:

```
object o = () =>{};  //this doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about:

```
object o = (Action) (() => { ... });
```

Though I don't really know why you'd want to store it as an object in the first place...

Comment: I am implement a message queue for a thread, command can be put in the queue for execution.

Comment: Hi, I'm kind of new here. What's the etiquette when someone posts an identical answer while I'm writing one. Should I just delete it? It seems kinds of superfluous now.

Comment: @Benny - If you can, consider using a generic structure like `Queue<Action>` so that the lambda expressions don't have to be cast as objects.

Comment: @Greg, well, sometime, i maybe want to put other object in the queue. so not just action.

Comment: @Spike - I'd leave your answer in place. It probably got more upvotes because you explained that delegates are objects.

Comment: @Spike, you don't have to delete it. that's how you get upvote. :)

Answer (score 11):

Weeeell, delegates are objects, but lambdas aren't.

This `object o = (Action)(() => {});` will compile, but I don't know if it looks any better.

Answer (score 6):

Another option, not all that different:

```
object o = new Action(() => { });
```

Comment: Actually, I like this one better. I mentally imagine the other solution as a constructor anyway. Might as well make it explicit.